# Chrome developer sidebar in extension pane

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I am making a developer extension for Chrome. I create a custom pane, and want to add a sidebar to that pane. [This page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools_panels) includes documentation on how to create a sidebar in the Elements pane and the Sources pane. However, it does not include any createSidebarPane method under the ExtensionPanel type. Is there a way to add a sidebar to extension panes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By hand.

If you're crating a whole panel, it's an HTML document under your full control.

But as a result, there is no "standard" framework embedded in *your* HTML that would allow for standard methods.